# Where's the puzzles?

Tags: discussion

I've seen lots of [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) and [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) questions, and few [code-bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling) and [code-curling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-curling) ones that didn't go over so well. What types of puzzles are there? Why aren't we seeing them?

Comment: Remember that, on this site, all puzzle types need to have an objective primary winning criterion. This restricts the kinds of puzzles you can have here, but I think this restriction is a good thing, because people can simply optimise their code towards that criterion.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than thinking of "programming puzzles" as a separate category my take has been that they are *all* puzzles.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill). The problem with that kind of question is best summed up by [Peter Taylor's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/194/peter-taylor) comments on [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4855/737).